# Relation between continuity of partial derivatives and existence of total differential

Tags: real-analysis, partial-derivative

In my textbook I have an example of a function that doesn't have a total differential, but it has partial derivatives :

Let f be a function from $\mathbb R^2$ to $\mathbb R$
$$f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 1 &\text{ if $x=0$ or $y=0$} \\ 0&\text{otherwise } \end{cases}$$

Partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ are:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0) =\, 0 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0,0)
$$
on the other hand, $f$ isn't continuous at $(0,0)$, so its total differential doesn't exist.

And below this there is a theorem saying if a function has continuous partial derivatives at a point $a$, then f has a total differential at $a$.

So partial derivatives of $f$ (example above) aren't continuous? It seems to me that partial derivatives are continuous because it is always zero. Where is the problem? Thank you.

Comment: A perhaps more interesting example, where the partial derivatives exist *everywhere* but $f$ is discontinuous at the origin, is $f(0,0)=1$ and $f(x,y)=(x+y)^2/(x^2+y^2)$ otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partial derivatives don't even exist in any neighborhood of $(0,0)$. For example the second partial derivative at $(1,0)$ is $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac {0-1} h$  which does not exist.

You can  conclude that the function is differentiable at $(0,0)$ if you  know that both partial derivatives exist is some open disk around the origin and that they are continuous functions.